# How to spyOn child components in Angular?

Tags: angular

In the Angular tutorials they have an example of a `HeroesComponent` with a child `HeroesListComponent`.

The `HeroesListComponent` uses a `HeroesService` to `getHeroes()`.

To `spyOn` `getHeroes()` inside `heroes-list.component.spec.ts`, we can do

```
spyOn(fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.heroesService, 'getHeroes').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve([]))
```

My question is: If I was inside of `HeroesComponent` spec file - `heroes.component.spec.ts` can I `spyOn` the child `HeroesListComponent` `getHeroes()` by doing something like this:

```
spyOn(fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.heroesListComponent.heroesService, 'getHeroes').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve([]))
```

Obviously this did not work, so I am asking if anyone can help me with a solution.

I want to do this, because I want to test if my `<hero-list>` loaded properly when I open `HeroesComponent`. This may seem repetitive as I already have a test to make sure `HeroesListComponent` works, but I think it's still an important test because I really want to make sure my `HeroesComponent` loaded properly and all of the child components too.

I also tried mocking the entire `HeroesService` inside of `HeroesComponent`, instead of using `spyOn`, but I can't get that syntax to work either. I don't know how to tell `HeroesListComponent` to use the mock object when i'm inside `heroes.component.spec.ts`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a stubbed child component where I wanted to confirm that certain functions on it were being called per my component's logic.

I was able to achieve this with the following setup.

Stub component:

```js
@Component({selector: 'child-component', template: ''})
class ChildComponentStub {
  someFunction() { /* ... */}
}
```

Test stage:

```js
it('should spy on a child component function', () => {
  const childComponent =
           fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ChildComponentStub))
               .componentInstance;

  const functionSpy = spyOn(childComponent, 'someFunction').and.callThrough();
       
  // test logic that causes someFunction to be called

  expect(functionSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

(Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796638/angular-5-testing-how-to-get-a-reference-to-the-child-component) that explains how to get a reference to a child component)

Answer (score 1):

In unit tests everything but tested unit is supposed to be mocked or stubbed. Original `<hero-list>` should be replaced with a mock:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-list',
  template: ''
})
class MockedHeroesListComponent {}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    HeroesComponent,
    MockedHeroesListComponent
  ]
});
```

`HeroesComponent` tests shouldn't test 
`heroesListComponent.heroesService`. All that should be asserted is that `<hero-list>` was compiled. `heroesListComponent.heroesService` should be tested in `HeroesListComponent` test with real `HeroesListComponent`.