# Angular 5 testing: how to get a reference to the child component

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to test the interaction between a host component and a child component in an Angular application. I don't know how to get a reference to the child component created when the parent gets created. Here is the setup:

**child.component.spec.ts**

```js
@Component({template: `<child [data]="model"></child>`})
class HostComponent {
  public model:any;
}

describe('ChildComponent', () => {
  let hostFixture: ComponentFixture<HostComponent>;
  let childFixture: ComponentFixture<ChildComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ChildComponent, HostComponent]
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    // this creates the child component as well, but how to get to it?
    hostFixture = TestBed.createComponent(HostComponent);

    // this creates a NEW instance of child component, not the one from the Host template
    // so it's not the instance I actually want to test
    childFixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChildComponent);
  });
});
```

Changing the `model` value in `hostFixture.componentInstance` doesn't actually change the `data` input value of `childFixture.componentInstance`; that's how I realized that there are two instances of child component.

My question is simple, how can I get `childFixture` to refer to the component fixture found in the `HostComponent` template, instead of a different instance as I currently have it?

[The docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component-inside-a-test-host-component) haven't been helpful.

Comment: Generally you can access the child's view using parent component fixture.Why the need for Child component fixture?

Comment: @AmitChigadani Because I'm interested in testing the component's properties and methods in reaction to changes in the input values set within the host template. An example would be testing two-way databinding between the host and the child.

Comment: How comes that the docs weren't helpful? This is exactly the scenario that is described there.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

As explained in [the guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host), host component instance is created with `TestBed.createComponent`, and child component instance can be selected from `debugElement` with [`By` helper](https://angular.io/guide/testing-utility-apis#componentfixture-methods):

```js
childDebugElement = hostFixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ChildComponent));
```

Or:

```js
childDebugElement = hostFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('child'));
```

Comment: Wouldn't your code give me a debugElement? I'm trying to get the component instance itself, not a template element.

Comment: It's not template element. It's https://angular.io/api/core/DebugElement . You can get the instance with `childDebugElement.componentInstance`.

Comment: I wanted to access the components properties. For me `childDebugElement.context` did the trick here. +1 for guiding me to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: It is more By.css('app-child') prefix must be included

Comment: If anyone else has the problem, that `By` is not available just like that, here is the import statement: `import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

Comment: The link to the Angular testing guide changed and is now https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host

Answer (score 13):

The answer above is good, answers the body's question, but the header/title of the question asks something else. I wanted to answer the question posed by the header as well. Estus's answer is correct for the specific use case, but Google brings you here based on the question in the title.

To get the child Component not the native element:

Test Component (called HostComponent in the question): `<child [data]="model" #child></child>`

Then in the class definition:

```js
@Component({template: `<child #child [data]="model"></child>`})
class HostComponent {
    public model:any;
    @ViewChild('child') child;
}
```

Finally, when testing, on a spec:

```js
it('should do something', () => {
    component.child.value
    component.child.method
    // etc.
}
```

You could use this in a test case, and I do, to find the child component that you're really trying to test.

---

The rest is to satisfy a debatable aspect brought up in the comments.

There's also a strong case for making things private when possible. I'm not sure how I feel about it if you want to unit test it. If you want to test a private member you have to let the typescript compiler that you want object with private members publicly accessible by casting it as  and wrapping it in parentheses to make it clear what you're casting.

In the component:

```js
...
    @ViewChild('child') private child;
...
```

In the test:

```js
...
    (<any>component).child.value
    (<any>component).child.method
...
```

Comment: I tried the spec provided by you, but i am getting `Cannot read property 'next' of undefined`. here, `next` is a method name i am trying to access.

Comment: @RohitJindal, what are you calling the next method on?

Comment: `@ViewChild('child') child;` should be private

Comment: @NagRock, thanks. I hadn't heard that before. Do you have documentation supporting that?

Answer (score 4):

Iterate through the childNodes of the debugElement(s) and access the context property to get access to the component ant its properties

```js
let debugElement = hostFixture.debugElement.childNodes[x] as DebugElement
debugElement = debugElement.childNodes[x] as DebugElement
...
let component = debugElement.context as YourComponent
```

This is a very static approach because if a new child is added then maybe you access the wrong childNode. It is better to write a helper method which traverse through the childNodes and find the right name.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  The accepted answer makes more sense to me because in that case, I could query directly for that component with `hostFixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ChildComponent))`.  That's what I did

Answer (score 4):

To access the child component instance (even typed):

```
const childComponent: ChildComponent = hostFixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ChildComponent)).componentInstance;
```

Comment: Worked for me to check the inputs received in the child component. Thanks!!